# First time using linux and trying to improve my pyenv experiance

Tags: shell, ubuntu, virtualization, pyenv

This is my first time using Linux and I need to use pyenv in the terminal (I am using a virtual ubuntu session on my windows machine). However, every time I start the windows terminal and shift to the ubuntu terminal, the following messages are shown. [Right after starting Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltV7c.png)

```
Command 'pyenv' not found, did you mean:

  command 'p7env' from deb libnss3-tools (2:3.49.1-1ubuntu1.5)
  command 'pyvenv' from deb python3-venv (3.8.2-0ubuntu2)

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>


Command 'pyenv' not found, did you mean:

  command 'pyvenv' from deb python3-venv (3.8.2-0ubuntu2)
  command 'p7env' from deb libnss3-tools (2:3.49.1-1ubuntu1.5)

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

Is there any way for this message to go away? I tried clearing the command history, but it still does not work.

Also, I am trying to write a shell script for all the commands I have to run every time. But the pyenv command just does not seems to work. [Image of my .sh file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbeh4.jpg)

```
echo "Welcome Back!!"
cd /mnt/c/Users/zml24/target_folder
exec bash
exec "$SHELL"
pyenv activate test
```

I think it is because it is a fish script instead of a bash command. Any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: Please don't include links to pictures. Insert the actual text from your files and terminal output using the code block formatting option into your post.

Comment: How did you install it? I'd recommend using https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer to install `pyenv`, and make sure you hook it to bash through `~/.bashrc` or similar.

Comment: I installed it by this github page: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.